# I am creating a library program. Should I transfer entire objects as books or their pointers?

Tags: java, object, memory

In my program, I books are objects and these books are kept in a shelf object which is kept in a library object. Inside the shelf object, I have a "reference" book that says what book the shelf is holding. But I also have an ArrayList that holds separate instances of the "reference" book. Again, it holds many reference variables that reference unique objects, they do not all reference the "reference" book.

So my question is...
When transferring a book to a user, should I be transferring each unique reference variable to the user and deleting the reference variable out of the list?
or....
Should I scrap the list and just copy pointers of the "reference" book to the users?

Note: A shelf has a set number of books that can be removed from it. I realize that the first choice would be a waste of memory. Also, in the second choice, I would just be keeping track of the amount of books left using an int variable. I would not be keeping track of the amount of book objects possessed by that shelf.

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you have multiple copies of the `Book` object for the same book? You've said the various places you have this, they're not all references to the one book. Why not? I could see having a `Book` per *copy* of the book that the library owns, but other than that, I'm not seeing it...

Comment: There is no such thing as a pointer in Java, there are only references and primitives.

Comment: Then excuse me, when you create an object in Java, it creates a reference variable to the object you just created. And when you set two objects equal to each other, it really creates two "references" to the same object.

Comment: That's my question. Should I simply transfer reference variables to the user that point to a singular "reference" book? Or should I have a new Book for each copy that's in the shelf and transfer that entire "Book" object to the user?              The reason I ask is, conserve vs be liberal with memory and conceptual transfer vs physical transfer. Which is better?

Comment: Your data model seems complex.  Though I don't doubt it's validity, you may be introducing more complexity than you need for your purpose. Rather than nesting objects, could you not simply make the "library" and the "shelf" properties of the book?  Only you can truly understand your abstraction, and perhaps it works well.  For my part, it seems to me that the thing in which you're most interested in managing is books.  A book "has a shelf to which it belongs" and "has a library" in which it is kept.  I would try to make those fields.  I anticipate that that would be simpler.